# Method not allowed when trying to access API methods via SOAP integration

Tags: docusignapi

Good day,

I'm having trouble calling DSAPI methods via SOAP ( C# Integration ). I keep getting 405 Method not allowed errors. So far I've tried calling the RequestTemplate and CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates methods, both of which fail. I was able to successfully retrieve the DSAPIServiceSoapClient object and also successfully login via the login method of the credential API. If you need more information, i'm ready to provide them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just needed to add the   in the X-DocuSign-Authentication http header whenever i try to get a DSAPIClient object.

Answer (score 0):

You're succeeding with the login, which is good.

My guess is that the other calls are not well formed. Perhaps they're missing the right base url (which you receive from the login call).

Are you switching to the different base url for your subsequent calls? (Different server name?)

I suggest that you try the API logging feature and see what it reports. It enables you to see a log of your API requests. See the [Request Logging article for the classic DocuSign experience](https://support.docusign.com/articles/API-Request-Logging), or the [new DocuSign UI](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging).